# Create graph for requests per minute and uri

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a table that looks like this.

```
time|uri
08:50:28|foo
08:51:42|bar
08:52:48|foo
08:53:49|bar
08:53:50|baz
08:54:02|bar
08:54:03|baz
08:55:27|foo
08:55:34|baz
08:56:47|bar
```

I would like to make a line graph with a line for each uri and the height of the line to be determined by the amount of requests per minute. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming Excel 2010 (but principle works in other versions:

1. Convert your data to an Excel Table.
2. Create a Pivot Table from your Excel Table data.  Use URI for your columns, Time (Grouped by Hour, Minute) for your rows, and URI Count for your Values.
3. Create a Chart from your Pivot Table.  You'll have to determine whether you want a regular Line or Stacked Line chart (based upon what you're trying to show).
4. Format to taste.

Here's what it could look like (Excel defaults in all of their glory):

[image: Line chart grouped by minute]